# Using std::filesystem::copy failed to copy symlink

Tags: c++, ubuntu

I want to copy ubuntu's iso file to usb key.

list of files and folders in iso:

```
.   boot          casper  dists  install     pool     ubuntu
..  boot.catalog  .disk   EFI    md5sum.txt  preseed
```

ubuntu appears to be a symlink

in c++ i've made this

```
auto const copyOption = std::filesystem::copy_options::recursive | std::filesystem::copy_options::copy_symlinks;
std::filesystem::copy("/mnt/iso", "/mnt/usb", copyOption);
```

copy finished with errors

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::filesystem_error'
  what():  filesystem error: cannot copy: Opération non permise [/mnt/iso] [/mnt/usb]
Abandon
```

how to fix this error?

Comment: Do your user have the permissions to do the operation?

Comment: yes i have. for example replace ```copy_symlinks``` by ```skip_symlinks ``` works

Comment: Can you try a dummy symlink to test the API ??

Comment: I'm on ubuntu. System files are ext4. but my usbkey was on fat32. Partitionning usbkey on ext4 and i can use ```copy_symlinks```